# Getting a frame from a Blackmagic device

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to start working with the Balckagic SDK. and I've  atrouble to get a frame the device "DeckLink SDI"

```
void    get_video(IDeckLink* decklink){
HRESULT                         result;
IDeckLinkInput*                 decklinkinput = NULL;
BSTR                            name = NULL;
IDeckLinkDisplayModeIterator*   displayModeIterator = NULL;
IDeckLinkInputCallback*         theCallback = NULL; 
IDeckLinkVideoInputFrame*       decklinkInputVideoframe =NULL;
IDeckLinkDisplayMode*           displayMode = NULL;
IDeckLinkVideoInputFrame*       inputVideoFrame;
IDeckLinkAudioInputPacket*      inputAudioPacket;
IBMDStreamingDeviceInput*       capture;
IDeckLinkVideoFrame*            deckLinkVideoFrame = NULL;
unsigned long                       avaibleFrames = NULL;


result = decklink->QueryInterface(IID_IDeckLinkInput,(void**) &decklinkinput);


result = decklinkinput->GetDisplayModeIterator(&displayModeIterator); 

result = decklinkinput->SetCallback(theCallback);
result = decklinkinput->EnableVideoInput(BMDDisplayMode::bmdModeHD1080i50,BMDPixelFormat::bmdFormat8BitYUV,bmdVideoInputEnableFormatDetection);
result = decklinkinput->DisableAudioInput();

result = decklinkinput->StartStreams();
decklinkinput->GetAvailableVideoFrameCount(&avaibleFrames); 




cout<<"Number of avaible frames " << avaibleFrames<<endl;
result = decklinkinput->SetCallback(theCallback);
theCallback->VideoInputFrameArrived(inputVideoFrame, inputAudioPacket);
result = decklinkinput->StopStreams();


}
```

and I don't have a syntax error all that I get is number of fram is 0. and i don't know how to save the frame. I'm  thankfull for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the code examples. The process:

1. Initialize the Decklink board
2. Register the callback and start streaming
3. Continue with other work on the main thread

Now every time a frame is available the Decklink SDK will call the registered callback function with the frame that it just processed. From the post above I get the feeling you do not grasp the concept of a callback.